# Can't run gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running gmapping on ROS Indigo. I installed gmapping by

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gmapping
rosmake gmapping
```

When I run it, I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData
However, when I run

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
```

I got this error:

slam_gmapping: tpp.c:62: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= __sched_fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= __sched_fifo_max_prio)' failed.

Aborted (core dumped)

How can I solve this? Any help is much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212596/can%27t-run-gmapping/) by [rosfuncoolstuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/22995/rosfuncoolstuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just updated pthread and boost, problem solved...

---

Originally posted by [rosfuncoolstuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/22995/rosfuncoolstuff/) with karma: 3 on 2015-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0